# Update Excel file (OpenXml format) with C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a requirement to update a few columns on every row in an Excel sheet that will be uploaded from a web browser (I need to decrypt the values that are in the sheet from those columns and replace them with the true values).  After the replacement happens, I will just push the updated file back down to the client.

I've worked with NPOI in the past but I'm wondering if there's a better solution out there now to accomplish this.  I did a little digging before making this post and found [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) but I couldn't find an easy way to do anything other than read Excel files using that library and my requirements are to do an update to the file.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's been years since I did this - but you can do anything you want using the Excel Object Model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/excel-object-model-overview?view=vs-2017

Comment: There's just one catch: every hour you spend automating Excel with .NET interop code subtracts one month from your life. Same goes for anyone who has to maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a real simple class using the [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) library. It updates an Excel file by reversing the text in the first column of every row. You can test it using any Excel spreadsheet with text in the first column.

Replace `ReverseText` with whatever it is that decrypts the value.

```
public class ExcelUpdater
{
    public void UpdateExcel(string pathToFile)
    {
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(pathToFile)))
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            var lastRow = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            for (var row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = ReverseText(worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Text);
            }
            package.Save();
        }
    }

    private string ReverseText(string value)
    {
        return new string(value.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```